# libyaml-cpp.s.0.2 not found

Tags: c++, ubuntu-12.04, ros, libyaml

I ran across a problem, probably because I deleted one day some files related to libyaml. Anyway when I try to build gscam (ros package) I get this error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libyaml-cpp.so.0.2, needed by /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libcamera_calibration_parsers.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/libcamera_calibration_parsers.so: undefined reference to `YAML::Node::begin() const'
```

And I can't find where I could get it. I mean, I've downloaded 0.3 version from here https://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/ and it works for my purposes. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to force a reinstall of the yaml-cpp package. See https://superuser.com/questions/102449/how-to-reinstall-a-package-using-apt-get for details on how to reinstall a package in Ubuntu.

In general, you shouldn't delete files that are installed by .deb packages.